# algorithm approach to render a node mesh in an overlap free way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mesh

I have a couple of nodes (e.g. application names) and a couple of edges with labels (e.g. information flows/system interfaces with their information objects). I would like to be able to code a javascript-script that draws me that node mesh (e.g. an information flow diagram) in an overlap free way, which means:

- labels of edges are not overlapped by nodes and/or each other
- nodes are not overlapped by edge lines and/or edge labels and/or each other

Also nodes need to be placed in a way that as much of the edge lines as possible is visible and not being confused with each other - so there needs to be some kind of optimization.
A requirement is also that any node could potentially be connected to any other node.

In order to do that I am looking for a rough idea on how to do that (high level pseudo code) or alternatively a ready-to-go javascript implementation.

I am not interested in the following as I know how that works:

- placing/moving divs
- drawing svg lines
- any kind of training how data transformation work or data assets must be (vectors, matrices, sparse matrices...)

I have started with something like:

1. put the nodes with just one edge to the outer space of the canvas
2. put nodes that connect to them close to them

That way I would have a tree that I can easily round-spread in my canvas. The initial idea was to do some sorting and grouping from there. However I have a hard time to group sub trees out of the mesh structure and somehow got stuck in that.

I was also thinking that collision detection might help me. However I did not get to the point how that could help me with placing nodes, so that edges are optimal in terms of being visible.

To make that even more visible here is how the input data structure looks like:

```js
var nodeseq=[  // id,name
{id:'i1',name:'app1'},
{id:'i2',name:'app2'};
...
];

var edgeseq=[  // id,sourcenodeid,targetnodeid,label
{id:'i1',sourcenodeid:'i33',targetnodeid:'i25',label:'Invoice'},
{id:'i2',sourcenodeid:'i3',targetnodeid:'i5',label:'Advise'},
...
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or alternatively a ready-to-go javascript implementation

[Springy.js](http://getspringy.com/) might suit your needs... It's been a while since I've last used it, but it has a pretty straight forward API so it might be worth it to give it a try. An example:

```js
var nodeseq = [  // id,name
  {id:'i1',name:'app1'},
  {id:'i2',name:'app2'},
  {id:'i3',name:'app3'},
  {id:'i4',name:'app4'},
];

var edgeseq = [  // id,sourcenodeid,targetnodeid,label
  {id:'i1',sourcenodeid:'i1',targetnodeid:'i2',label:'Invoice'},
  {id:'i2',sourcenodeid:'i1',targetnodeid:'i3',label:'Advise'},
  {id:'i3',sourcenodeid:'i3',targetnodeid:'i3',label:'Test'},
  {id:'i4',sourcenodeid:'i3',targetnodeid:'i4',label:'Test'},
  {id:'i5',sourcenodeid:'i2',targetnodeid:'i3',label:'Test'},
];

var graph = new Springy.Graph();
var createNode = node => graph.newNode({label: node.name });

var nodeMap = makeMap("id", nodeseq, createNode);

// connect them with an edge
edgeseq.forEach(edge => graph.newEdge(
  nodeMap[edge.sourcenodeid],
  nodeMap[edge.targetnodeid],
  { label: edge.label }
));

$('canvas').springy({ graph: graph });

// Utils
function makeMap(prop, arr, t) {
  t = t || (v => v);
  return arr
    .reduce((map, item) => Object.assign(map, { 
      [item[prop]] : t(item) 
      }), {}); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springyui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springy.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="400" height="200" />
```

Comment: Wow. Is there a possibility to put labels to the edges as well?

Comment: Sure, the `newEdge` method takes a third argument that allows you to specify attributes. I've edited the example in my answer; we now pass the `label` property to label the arrows.